# How to load a custom DLL into PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, .net-standard, powershell-5.0

I've been trying to load a custom DLL into PowerShell with no luck.

My DLL's are being created [based on this repository](https://github.com/Kellen-Stuart/DnD). My end goal is to be able to load `Monster.dll` but I figured I'd start with `Dice.dll` (because it's a static class with practically no dependencies).

**What I've tried**

In PowerShell:

`cd C:\some\repo\dnd\dice\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1`

`$path = (pwd).Path`

`$path += "\Dice.dll"`

`[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$path")`

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\some\repo\dnd\dice\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\Dice.dll
```

And then I try to call the simple Roll Dice function (which looks like this)

`[Dice.Dice]::Roll(20, 1)`

And it returns this error:

```
Unable to find type [Dice.Dice].
At line:1 char:1
+ [Dice.Dice]::Roll(20, 1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Dice.Dice:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

The same thing happens if I try to call:

`[Dice]::Roll(20, 1)`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Someone suggested that I try:

`Add-Type -Path "$path"`

and it returns this error:

```
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path "$path"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

The real "LoadExeption" is

```
Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Another suggestion from the comments was to run:

`[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies()`

I was able to find this data from that command

```
@{CodeBase=file:///C:/some/Repo/DnD/dice/bin/Debug/netstandard2.1/Dice.dll; FullName=Dice,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null; EntryPoint=; DefinedTypes=; Evidence=System.Security.Policy.Evidence;
PermissionSet=<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>
; SecurityRuleSet=Level2; ManifestModule=Dice.dll; ReflectionOnly=False;
Location=C:\some\Repo\DnD\dice\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\Dice.dll; ImageRuntimeVersion=v4.0.30319;
GlobalAssemblyCache=False; HostContext=0; IsDynamic=False;
EscapedCodeBase=file:///C:/some/Repo/DnD/dice/bin/Debug/netstandard2.1/Dice.dll; ExportedTypes=;
IsFullyTrusted=True; CustomAttributes=; Modules=System.Reflection.RuntimeModule[]}
```

I also ran this command:

```
try {
    ([appdomain]::currentdomain.GetAssemblies() | where Location -match 'dice').gettypes()
} catch {
    $_ | select *
}
```

```
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetTypes" with "0" argument(s):
                        "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
                        information." ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested
                        types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
                           at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
                           at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext,
                        Exception exception)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
```

Comment: Does `Add-Type -Path $path` work?

Comment: @AdminOfThings I added an update to my question - I did not work, unfortunately. It looks like it couldn't load `.netstandard` or something? I like your name btw

Comment: Since you did not get the error using `[Reflection.Assembly]` but did using `Add-Type` I would review the value of $path to ensure it is pointing to the correct location. Can you run `[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies()  | format-table fullname ,location` and filter to your assembly. This will tell us the location and assembly name that you did load using `[Reflection.Assembly]`

Comment: @BrandonMcClure I added more details based on your question and the command you posted.

Comment: For anyone interested - the entire problem was using .NET Standard. Once I re-created the project in .NET Core, `Add-Type -AssemblyName .\Dice.dll` worked like a charm! Only took me the entire day to figure out :p

Comment: I got the same error as you `Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types`. But how can I get  real "LoadExeption" ?

Comment: @Mark You could try to pipe to select `Add-Type .... | select *`. You can also store it in a variable `$output = Add-Type ...` and then explore properties on the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key info is in the "LoadException" message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It says that the assembly `netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0` can't be found. That prevents PowerShell from loading Dice, because Dice is compiled against .NET Standard 2.1.

I'm not sure about the nuances of .NET Standard 2.1 support through PowerShell. You might need a newer version of PowerShell, or you might just need to install the right .NET SDK/runtime components.

If you aren't tied to .NET Standard 2.1, try re-configuring the C# project to target .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Framework 4.7 (or lower).

Comment: So get this: I've been working on this all day and finally decided to convert the Dice class over to .NET Core - and the second I did that `Add-Type -AssemblyName .\Dice.dll` worked instantly! I can't believe the entire problem was PowerShell not supporting .NET Standard!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post my own answer because I'd like to help others with this issue.

If you're getting an error like this, make sure you follow these steps:

- Upgrade to the most recent version of .NET Core
- Upgrade PowerShell to the most recent version available. It must support the version of .NET Core you are using
- When you call the method, use the PassThru parameter to get more verbose errors

`Add-Type -AssemblyName "C:\path\to\file.dll" -PassThru`

**Again, the root of my problem stemmed from being on PowerShell 5** while trying to use .NET Core. If you look at where PowerShell is installed, it includes its own .NET Core DLLs which will be different from your global installation.

I ended up installing PowerShell 7 Preview because (at the time this is written) , it was the only version that supported .NET Core 3.*